# Nashorn, Java collections, How to implement equals and hashCode in pure javascript

Tags: java, javascript, equals, hashcode, nashorn

I’ve faced with the following problem. I’d like to use `java.util.HashMap` and `java.util.PriorityQueue` in **Nashorn** script, where I need to use particular custom object as a *key in the HashMap*, and also use `HashMap.containsKey()` to check if there is a key in the Map (another option is to check if the object in a Collection.contains(Object o)).

So, obviously, I need to implement equals and hashCode in my object basing on some field values.

For example:

1. Trying to use JavaScript. Doesn’t work due to JavaScript doesn’t have those methods. Please see **Sample 1** and **Sample 2**
2. Extending java.lang.Object. **Sample 3**. Works partially, Methods are being invoked. But

   - *How to plugin constructor with parameters?*
   - *How to do the cast from this:[object Object] to other:jdk.nashorn.javaadapters.java.lang.Object@0, or vice versa?*
3. Implementing my custom class in Java and extend it in JavaScript. **Sample 4**. Works. But do I need Nashorn if I have to use Java?

```js
var PriorityQueue = java.util.PriorityQueue;
var HashMap = java.util.HashMap;
var Integer = java.lang.Integer;

// Sample 1
// Doesn't work, equals and hashCode are not being invoked
function Vertex1(from, cost) {
    this.from = from;
    this.cost = cost;

    this.equals = function(other) { return this.from == other.from; }
    this.hashCode = function() { return Integer.hashCode(this.from); }
}

var hm = new HashMap();
hm.put(new Vertex1(1, 10), 10);
hm.put(new Vertex1(1, 20), 21);
// Prints size is 2, but I'd like to see 1
print("HashMap size: " + hm.size());
// Prints false
print("HashMap1 contains: " + hm.containsKey(new Vertex1(1, 20)));

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Sample 2
// Doesn't work, equals and hashCode are not being invoked
function Vertex1(from, cost) {
    this.from = from;
    this.cost = cost;
}
Vertex1.prototype = {
    equals : function(other) { return this.from == other.from; },
    hashCode : function() { return Integer.hashCode(this.from); },
}
var hm = new HashMap();
hm.put(new Vertex1(1, 10), 10);
hm.put(new Vertex1(1, 20), 21);
// Prints size is 2, but I'd like to see 1
print("HashMap size: " + hm.size());
// Prints false
print("HashMap1 contains: " + hm.containsKey(new Vertex1(1, 20)));

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Sample 3
// Works partially, Methods are being invoked. But 

// 1. How to plugin construstor with parameters?
// 2. How to do the cast from this:[object Object] to other:jdk.nashorn.javaadapters.java.lang.Object@0, or vice versa

var JObject = Java.type("java.lang.Object");
var Vertex2 = Java.extend(JObject, {
    from : 0,
    equals : function(other) { return this.from.equals(other.from); },
    hashCode : function() { return Integer.hashCode(this.from); },
});
var hm = new HashMap();
// How to implement constructor for new Vertex2(10, 10)?
hm.put(new Vertex2(), 10);
hm.put(new Vertex2(), 21);
// Prints size is 2, because hashCode is the same and equals returns false
print("HashMap size: " + hm.size());
// Prints false, because equals returns false
print("HashMap1 contains: " + hm.containsKey(new Vertex2()));

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Sample 4
// com.arsenyko.MyObject is implemented in Java, Works, but Nashorn is ambiguous then!!!
var MyObject = Java.type("com.arsenyko.MyObject");
var Vertex2 = Java.extend(MyObject, {});
var hm = new HashMap();
hm.put(new Vertex2(1, 10), 10);
hm.put(new Vertex2(1, 20), 21);
print("HashMap size: " + hm.size());
print("HashMap1 contains: " + hm.containsKey(new Vertex2(1, 10)));
```

**EDIT 1**

@Tomasz, thanks. Have seen all the mentioned links. But though that somewhat undocumented exists. Almost gave up with Nashorn. Came to the following partial solution, methods are being invoked, constructor is being used, but **how to cast `other.from` in the `equals` method in order to get access to the `from` field of the original object** (this code produces different classes for each instance of a Vertex):

```js
//load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");
var PriorityQueue = java.util.PriorityQueue;
var HashMap = java.util.HashMap;
var Integer = java.lang.Integer;

function Vertex1(from, cost) {
    this.from = from;
    this.cost = cost;

    this.equals = function(other) {
        var value1 = this.from;
        // How to get other.from here???
        var value2 = other.from;
        print('value1=' + value1 + ' value2=' + value2);
        print(other);
        var eq = value1.equals(value2);
        print('equals is ' + eq);
        return eq;
    }
    this.hashCode = function() {
        var hashCode = Integer.hashCode(this.from);
        print('hashCode is ' + hashCode);
        return hashCode;
    }

    var JObject = Java.type("java.lang.Object");
    // return Java.extend(JObject, this); // doesn't work
    // return this; // doesn't work
    // return new JavaAdapter(java.lang.Object, this); // Works! with load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");
    var Type = Java.extend.apply(Java, [JObject]);
    return new Type(this);
}

var hm = new HashMap();
hm.put(new Vertex1(1, 10), 10);
hm.put(new Vertex1(1, 20), 21);
// Prints size is 2, but I'd like to see 1
print("HashMap size: " + hm.size());
// Prints false
print("HashMap contains: " + hm.containsKey(new Vertex1(1, 20)));
```

**EDIT 2**

Thanks for Tomasz, as he pointed out, Every invocation of the Java.extend() function with a class-specific implementation object produces a new Java adapter class. Thus we need to have one Object Extender and instantiate objects with that one type, as he showed in his sample. I modified it a little bit, so it produces instances with the same class with either factory or direct constructor, since we are using the same Object Extender

```js
var HashMap = java.util.HashMap;
var JInteger = java.lang.Integer;
var JObject = Java.extend(java.lang.Object);

var createVertex = (function() {
    var
    _equals = function(other) {
        print(this + ' vs ' + other);
        return this._from === other.from;
    };
    _hashCode = function() {
        var hashCode = JInteger.hashCode(this._from);
        print(hashCode);
        return hashCode;    
    };
    return function(from, cost) {
        return new JObject() {
            _from : from,
            _cost : cost,
            equals : _equals,
            hashCode : _hashCode,
        }
    }
})();

var JSVertex = function(from, cost) {
    return new JObject() {
        _from : from,
        _cost : cost,
        equals : function(other) {
            print(this + ' vs ' + other);
            return this._from === other._from;
        },
        hashCode : function() {
            var hashCode = JInteger.hashCode(this._from);
            print(hashCode);
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}

var v1 = JSVertex(1, 10);
var v2 = JSVertex(1, 20);
//var v1 = createVertex(1, 10);
//var v2 = createVertex(1, 20);
var v3 = createVertex(1, 20);
print(v1.class === v2.class); // returns true
print(v2.class === v3.class); // returns true
var hm = new HashMap();
hm.put(v1, 10);
hm.put(v2, 21);
print("HashMap size: " + hm.size()); // Prints 2, but I'd like to see 1
print("HashMap contains: " + hm.containsKey(v3)); // Prints false
```

However, there is a still an issue, the type of the parameter of the `equals` is `jdk.nashorn.javaadapters.java.lang.Object`, in other words the `other` and `this` inside `equals` are different types. **Is there a way, to cast or get `_from` value from the object passed to the `equals`**?

**THE SOLUTION**

**See the solution for the problem is in the Tomasz's answer**.

Great work Tomasz! Thanks.

PS : It's very sad that there is no neat and straightforward way to implement `equals` and `hashCode` in Nashorn. It would be useful for prototyping. Just compare that with this :)

```groovy
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
@EqualsAndHashCode(excludes="cost")
class Vertex {
   int from, cost
}
```

Comment: Hi, my answer had some errors. I fixed them (edited the answer once again). With Nashorn it seems to be more compicated than with Rhino.

Comment: Hi, two notices: 1. if `JSVertex` is a function which returns `new JObject() { ...` you do not need to call `new` when calling it - just call `var v1 = JSVertex(1, 10);`; 2. In your `createVertex`you do not need an anonymous function to return actual function if you do not hide any "private" variables inside the anonymous function call (which was the case earlier in my example).

Comment: As to reading (and setting) custom properties on java objects in javascript - it seems to be another flaw in Nashorn (I do not remember how it was in Rhino) - I'll give antoher edit to my answer later to address it.

Comment: Hi, you are right, have fixed you notices in the code.

Comment: JavaDoc of [JavaAdapterBytecodeGenerator](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/nashorn/jdk8/nashorn/file/18edd7a1b166/src/jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/linker/JavaAdapterBytecodeGenerator.java) says

Comment: JavaDoc of [JavaAdapterBytecodeGenerator](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/nashorn/jdk8/nashorn/file/18edd7a1b166/src/jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/linker/JavaAdapterBytecodeGenerator.java) says `java.lang.Object` methods `equals`, `hashCode`, `toString` can also be overridden... All other adapter methods can be implemented or overridden through a prototype-inherited function of the ScriptObject passed to the constructor too...

Comment: @tomasz-gawel Does it relate to [JSAdapter](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-JSAdapterconstructor)?

Comment: something close to - i used `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.AbstractJSObject` to access "dynamic properties"

Comment: I finally edited answer once again.

Comment: That stray `var` on a line by itself is strange. Is there supposed to be a comma after the definition of `_equals` instead of a semicolon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Rhino you would use :

```
var vertex = new JavaAdapter(java.lang.Object, new Vertex(1, 10));
hm.put(vertex, 10);
```

to make the JavaScript methods override same named Java methods from java.lang.Object (see reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java#The_JavaAdapter_Constructor)

Maybe there is a similar construct in Nashorn.

**EDIT:**

You may use Rhino syntax in Nashorn. Just put the line :

```
load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");
```

See: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Rhino+Migration+Guide

**EDIT: (AGAIN)**

With Nashorn it seems to be much more complicated:

```
// we will need a factory method
var createVertex = (function() { // i hope you are familiar with "inline" function calls

    // private variables used in every call of factory method - but initialized once
    var 
        JObjExtender = Java.extend(Java.type("java.lang.Object")),
        JInteger = Java.type("java.lang.Integer"),
        _equals = function(other) { 
            return this.from === other.from; 
        },
        _hashCode = function() { 
            return JInteger.hashCode(+this.from); // leading "+" converts to number
        };

    // the "actual" factory method
    return function(from, cost) {
        return new JObjExtender() {
            from : from,
            cost : cost, 
            equals : _equals,
            hashCode : _hashCode
        };
    };
})();

var vertex = createVertex(1, 10);
hm.put(vertex, 10);
```

See 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html

What is more interesting, if you create multiple instances like below:

```
var v1 = createVertex(1, 10);
var v2 = createVertex(1, 20);
```

Then they are of the same class (I expected them to be instances of two anonymous sunclasses of `Object`).

```
var classEquals = (v1.class === v2.class); // produces : true
```

**A TRICK:**

Although in Nashorn you can NOT extend non-abstract classes on the fly like:

```
var v1 = new java.lang.Object(new JSVertex(10, 10));
// produces: TypeError: Can not construct java.lang.Object with the passed
// arguments; they do not match any of its constructor signatures.
```

You may extend in this way any abstract classes or interfaces. (And as any anonymous class implementing an interface also extends Object so you can overwrite `equals` or `hashCode` methods too).

To illustrate this, consider you have a JavaScript "prototype-class":

```
var JSVertex = function (from, cost) {
    this.from = from;
    this.cost = cost;
};
JSVertex.prototype = {
    equals : function(other) { 
        return this.from === other.from; 
    },
    hashCode : function() { 
        return java.lang.Integer.hashCode(+this.from); // leading "+" converts to number
    },
    compare : function(other) {
        return this.from - (+other.from);
    }
};
```

now you can create its "Java-wrapped" instances as below:

```
var v1 = new java.lang.Comparable(new JSVertex(10, 10));
print(v1.class); 
// produces both: class jdk.nashorn.javaadapters.java.lang.Object and
// class jdk.nashorn.javaadapters.java.lang.Comparable

var v2 = new java.lang.Comparable(new JSVertex(11, 12));
print(v2 instanceof java.lang.Object); // produces true
print(v2 instanceof java.lang.Comparable); // produces true
```

Knowing that you can create an empty Java interface to enable such wrappers without a need for additional method implementations to be provided (like `compare` in the example with `Comparable` above).

**PROBLEM**

As You pointed out the objects created in both ways presented above are Java objects with fixed "interface". Thus any method or field from wrapped JavaScript object, which has not been explicitly specified by implented interfaces, or classes will NOT be accessible from javascript.

**THE SOLUTION**

After some fiddling I found the solution to the above problem. A key to it is `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.AbstractJSObject` class from Nashorn scripting API.

Consider we have JSVertex "javascript class" (very similar to already presented above):

```
var JSVertex = function (from, cost) {
    this.from = +from;
    this.cost = +cost;
};
JSVertex.prototype = {
    equals : function(other) { 
        print("[JSVertex.prototype.equals " + this + "]");
        return this.from === other.from;
    },
    hashCode : function() { 
        var hash = java.lang.Integer.hashCode(this.from);
        print("[JSVertex.prototype.hashCode " + this + " : " + hash + "]");
        return hash;
    },
    toString : function() {
        return "[object JSVertex(from: " + 
            this.from + ", cost: " + this.cost + ")]";
    },
    // this is a custom method not defined in any Java class or Interface
    calculate : function(to) { 
        return Math.abs(+to - this.from) * this.cost;
    }
};
```

Let's create a function which will allow us to wrap Java Object over any JavaScript object in that way, that any same-named method from the JavaScript object would "extend" corresponding Java Object method.

```
var wrapJso = (function() { 

    var 
        JObjExtender = Java.extend(Java.type(
            "jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.AbstractJSObject")),
        _getMember = function(name) {
            return this.jso[name];
        },
        _setMember = function(name, value) {
            this.jso[name] = value;
        },
        _toString = function() { 
            return this.jso.toString();
        };

    return function(jsObject) {
        var F = function() {};
        F.prototype = jsObject;
        var f = new F();
        f.jso = jsObject;
        f.getMember = _getMember;
        f.setMember = _setMember;
        f.toString = _toString; // "toString hack" - explained later
        return new JObjExtender(f);
    };
})();
```

Finally having written that all let's see it working.

Create a wrapper over JSVertex object and do some tests on it:

```
var wrapped = wrapJso(new JSVertex(11,12));

// access custom js property and method not defined in any java class 
// or interface.
print(wrapped.from);
print(wrapped.calculate(17));

print("--------------");

// call toString() and hashCode() from JavaScript on wrapper object
print(wrapped.toString());
print(wrapped.hashCode());

print("--------------");

// Use StringBuilder to make Java call toString() on our wrapper object.
print(new java.lang.StringBuilder().append(wrapped).toString() );
// see hack in wrapJso() - for some reason java does not see 
// overriden toString if it is defined as prototype member.

// Do some operations on HashMap to get hashCode() mehod called from java
var map = new java.util.HashMap();
map.put(wrapped, 10);
map.get(wrapped);

wrapped.from = 77;
map.get(wrapped);

print("--------------");

// let's show that modyfing any of pair: wrapped or jso touches underlying jso.
var jso = new JSVertex(17,128);
wrapped = wrapJso(jso);
print(wrapped);
jso.from = 9;
wrapped.cost = 10;
print(wrapped);
print(jso);
print(jso == wrapped);
```

The output:

```
11
72
--------------
[object JSVertex(from: 11, cost: 12)]
[JSVertex.prototype.hashCode [object JSVertex(from: 11, cost: 12)] : 11]
11
--------------
[object JSVertex(from: 11, cost: 12)]
[JSVertex.prototype.hashCode [object JSVertex(from: 11, cost: 12)] : 11]
[JSVertex.prototype.hashCode [object JSVertex(from: 11, cost: 12)] : 11]
[JSVertex.prototype.hashCode [object JSVertex(from: 77, cost: 12)] : 77]
--------------
[object JSVertex(from: 17, cost: 128)]
[object JSVertex(from: 9, cost: 10)]
[object JSVertex(from: 9, cost: 10)]
false
```

Comment: Thank you, I edited the post with still remaining question, how to access `other.from` from `jdk.nashorn.javaadapters.java.lang.Object` possibly you could help.

Comment: Sorry I made some mistake in the answer, which you followed. The problem was that `Java.extend(Java.type("java.lang.Object"), jsObject)` in fact did not create a new object but a "template" for creating ne wextended objects. After my last edit the answer should now show proper usage scenario.

Comment: After saying that I would tend to define data structures in Java - and I would only "script them" in JavaScript. ;)

Comment: Modified your code a little bit, you found a good trick, but as you mentioned, it requires to code in Java. So, if I have to code a part of that in Java, then I don't need Nashorn with "tricks" at all :). It's obviously "no-question" implementation in Java, Scala, Groovy, etc. But I'm disappointed, that there is a scripting language which comes with JDK, and it'll be very useful to use just a text editor and scratch something there and run it from console, but there is no obvious way to script basic things!